# parallel reduction technique

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I have this piece of C++ code and I want to port it to CUDA.

```
for (int im = 0; im < numImages; im++)
{
    for (p = 0; p < xsize*ysize; p++) 
    {
        bool ok = false;

        for (f = 0; f < numFeatures; f++)
        {
            if (feature[im][f][p] != 0) 
            {
                ok = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ok)
        {         
            minDist = 1e9;
            for (i = 0; i < numBins; i++) 
            {
                dist = 0;
                for (f = 0; f < numFeatures; f++)
                {
                    dist += (float)((feature[im][f][p]-clusterPoint[f][i])*(feature[im][f][p]-clusterPoint[f][i]));
                }

                if (dist < minDist) 
                {
                    minDist = dist;
                    tmp = i;          
                }
            }//end for i  

            for (f = 0; f < numFeatures; f++) 
                csum[f][tmp] += feature[im][f][p];

            ccount[tmp]++;

            averageDist[tmp] += sqrt(minDist);

        } // end if (ok)
    }  //end for p    
}// end for im
```

I want to calculate `csum`,`ccount` and `averageDist` in the GPU. `csum` and `averagedist` are floats, `ccount` is an integer.

Is this a parallel reduction problem?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understand what your code should do and I do not know what are approximate values of `numBins` and `numFeatures` as well. Nevertheless, I would make parallel this loop: `for (p = 0; p < xsize*ysize; p++)`, in order to each thread computes its values and stores them in global array. Having these arrays of *features* and *distances* you can compute `csum`, `ccount` and `averageDist` using standard parallel reduction.

Main loop over *images* `for (int im = 0; im < numImages; im++)` is possible to compute by repetitive launching of kernel or it is also possible to make it parallel at once with loop over pixels.

In a case of `if(ok)` is not satisfied enough frequently, warp divergence occurs (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532858/how-can-warps-in-the-same-block-diverge)). Avoiding this you can assign nor one thread to each pixel but one warp and divide remaining computations among the threads within this warp.

Comment: thank you for your answers! Let's say numImages =1 and xsize*ysize=307200, numBins=80, numFeatures=7. I'm sorry I didn't make that clear. If I understand correctly you advise me to have a kernel that stores all the arrays I need to calculate csum ccount and averageDist as device variables. And when that first kernel finishes then call my parallel reduction kernel for each of my desired arrays. Is that right? Thanks again

Comment: Yes it is. Compute needed values in parallel in one kernel and then make reduction of arrays in next kernel(s).

Answer (score 0):

Ya, you can use CUDA for summations. But, the number of elements should be large enough such that the time elapsed for summation on GPU should be less than time elapsed for summation on CPU. [This may help you](http://www.cse.nd.edu/courses/cse40833/www/kogge_gpu/lectures/logsum.pdf)